# Lower case column names when using SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, kohana

I'm using the Kohana framework and I need to convert column names to lowercase. I don't have control of the db table structure. I want to do the following:
`SELECT LOWER(*) FROM .....`

but MYSQL does not like that. Whats the proper way of outputting the lower case column names if I don't know what the column names will be?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Comment: I really need it in my SELECT statement. Because it is just one complicated SELECT that is returning an object.

Comment: You would have to build a SELECT statement using dynamic SQL and something like @jon3laze's answer below.  There is no other way if you do not know the column names before executing the query.

Comment: I added the correct MySQL syntax to my answer.

Comment: column name is case insensitive in mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

```
SELECT LOWER(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Table'
```

Below you can see both MSSQL and MySQL syntax for creating a dynamic query using the column results from the query above.

**MSSQL Syntax**

---

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames [nvarchar](1024)

SELECT @ColumnNames = COALESCE(@ColumnNames + ', ', '') + LOWER(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table'

DECLARE @Sql [nvarchar](1024) = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnNames + ' FROM Table ' --Remember to put spaces after SELECT and before FROM

EXEC(@Sql)
```

With this you are dynamically building your query and then executing it.

**MySQL Syntax**

---

```
SELECT @ColumnNames := GROUP_CONCAT(LOWER(COLUMN_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table';

SET @Sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @ColumnNames, ' FROM Table ');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @Sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: The only thing is that I don't know the column names because there are several dynamically added JOINS. So whatever the final output is they need to be lowercase.

Comment: This Query gives you all of the column names for the given table. The only thing you would need to do is replace `'Table'` with the name of the table that you need the column names from. If it is more complex than that please post the full query you are working with.

Comment: I'll try to translate it into mysql.

Comment: I know MySQL has the `COALESCE` function. I'm not 100% on the execution of a query stored as a string. Try what I have and then if there are errors Google for MySQL execute variable as query. Good Luck and thanks for the challenge :P